# Error opening Interbase database with IBExpert

Tags: firebird, interbase, ibexpert

**wrong or obsolete version. unsupported on-disk structure for file C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\ADMINISTRATOR\DESKTOP\BD.IB; found 11.2, support 11.2**

When I went to open an Interbase database with IBExpert, I found this message.
I am using the Firebird service to access the database.

I tried to open it in other PC's, with Interbase server, and the same error appears.

I need help. I can't open my database.

---

I formatted my PC, and installed Interbase XE Server Trial Version 32 bits. On the installation I encountered an error saying the file "ibnodeid.exe" cannot be executed. But I finished the installation, and did not can start Interbase Server (I think was something related to the file "ibnodeid.exe").

After that, I downloaded the new Firebird (2.5.1.26351), and the same error (unsupported .....) appeared.

How I can restore the database? It's very important.

And I'm so sorry for replying so late. Didn't have time to solve this issue, but I'm back. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Try to backup and restore database

Comment: Which client library you use in IBExpert ?

Comment: it's better use fbclient.dll for Firebird

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Interbase and Firebird have an incompatible binary file formats. In order to access Interbase database file you need to install Interbase server.

Comment: But I tried to access the database with Interbase server. The same error occurs.

Comment: Do you have Interbase and Firebird servers on the same machine? Are they share the same port number?

Comment: I tried on different machines, each with only one service installed.

Comment: Did you try gfix on the database?

Comment: I'll search and try to fix the database.

Comment: I tried some gfix commands, and all of them returned the message "unsuported on-disk......" - the same message I found before.

Comment: What versions of Interbase and Firebird do you use? Syntax of gfix is gfix -v -full database_name -pas masterkey -user sysdba

Comment: I'm using Firebird 2.5, and Interbase 6.0. And the result of "gfix -v -full [database_path] -pas masterkey -user sysdba" is the same message ("unsupported ......").

Comment: Try latest Firebird 2.5.1 or 2.5.2 (latter accessible through snapshot download area on the oficial web site)

Answer (score 0):

-

I think the only released version of Interbase is 10.x, I don't know about Firebird, but it may be lower numbers. This leads me to think you are trying to work with a Beta version of IB. Very interesting!

Comment: Please check list of all ODS numbers for Interbase and Firebird http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ODSVersion

Comment: My mistake. I was responding to version number, not ODS number.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database is corrupted. Your database isn't Interbase 6 (that had ODS 10, not 11.2), and it looks like Firebird 2.5 thinks it is ODS 11.2, but still cannot read the database.

I think your only option is to restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

First find out what the version of the database is with the command gstat -h database_name.gdb.

With this you can now install the corresponding version of Firebird or Interbase.

Database created with version:   ODS version:

InterBase® 5 ->                    9

InterBase® 5.5 / 5.6 ->            9.1

InterBase® 6 / Firebird 1.0 ->        10.0

InterBase® 6.5 / Firebird 1.5 ->      10.1

InterBase® 7 / Firebird 2.0 ->      11

InterBase® 7.1 / Firebird 2.1 ->      11.1

InterBase® 7.5 / Firebird 2.5 ->      11.2

InterBase® 2007 / Firebird 3.0  ->  12

InterBase® 2009 / Firebird 4.0 ->     13

InterBase® XE ->                      15.0

Answer (score 0):

Anything beyond ODS 10.0, I would not recommend using InterBase server to access Firebird databases, and vice versa. Use the compatible database server to access their own ODS versions.

For InterBase databases, use the following server version(s)...

- InterBase XE/XE3 -> Primary ODS version: 15, supports up to ODS version 11
- InterBase XE7 -> Primary ODS version: 16.x, supports OLTP on ODS version upto 13; ODS versions 11 and 12 only for "database backup" purposes
- InterBase 2017 -> Primary ODS version: 17.x, supports OLTP on ODS version upto 13; ODS versions 11 and 12 only for "database backup" purposes
- InterBase 2020 -> Primary ODS version: 18.x, supports OLTP on ODS version upto 13; ODS versions 11 and 12 only for "database backup" purposes

If you have any InterBase database in backup format, you can restore it to a current version of the database engine. It will be restored with the primary ODS version supported. If you'd like to restore to a older ODS version, all servers from InterBase XE7 onwards (to the current 2020 version) will allow you to restore to an ODS version as far back as version 13.